# Find Laurent expansion of rational function

Tags: complex-analysis

I wish to find Laurent expansion of $$ \frac{\left(b_{0}+b_{2}\right)z^{2}+\left(b_{2}a_{1}+b_{1}\right)z+a_{2}b_{2}}{z^{2}+a_{1}z+a_{2}}, $$

where $b_0,b_1,b_2,a_1,a_2 $ are unknown real constants (but non-zero).

Basically, it would be enough to find Laurent expansion of $$ \frac{1}{z^{2}+a_{1}z+a_{2}} .$$

If I'm only intrested only in specific coefficients, for example $(c_0,c_1,c_2$). Is there more efficient way to do it then fraction decomposition?

Comment: You can write it in the form $c/(z-r_1)+c/(z-r_2)$ where $r_1,r_2$ are the roots of $x^2+a_1z+a_0$; does that help?

Comment: @GregMartin I edit the original post, yes ofcourse its possible but seems like a lot of work since I dont know the coefficients. Assume Im only intrested in a few specific coefficients, is there a way to calculate those coefficients without finding the whole expansion?

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: @GregMartin I'll try. About the first way, can you explain  why we get different expansion when we write the rational function as I wrote in the original post and when we write it as $ \frac{\left(b_{0}+b_{2}\right)+\left(b_{2}a_{1}+b_{1}\right)z^{-1}+a_{2}b_{2}z^{-2}}{a_{2}z^{-2}+a_{1}z^{-1}+1} $ ? (multiplied numerator and denominator by $z^-2$ I mean, in the latter way we get a series of $z^-1 $ which is not analytic, and in the first way we get a series of $z $  which is analytic. How it this possible? its the same function

Comment: A function can have different Laurent expansions in different annuli.

Comment: @GregMartin But the function is still holomorphic at $z=0$, so how come the analytic part vanish when the principal part should vanish?

Comment: The Laurent expansion in $z^{-1}$ is valid in the annulus $0<|z|\le \infty$ (with the abuse of notation at infinity). On that annulus, that's how Laurent expansions look.